# Django: Creating a function-based view Login & Signup form in one single page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a landing page similar to linkedin's where it has the signup form and the login form at the navbar. I'm currently using a single form for both the signup and login in forms.py:

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label='')
lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label='')
email = forms.EmailField(label='')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password1']
```

My template includes 2 `{{ form }}`s and each has a submit button.

Button for the sign up `{{ form }}`:

```
name='signupbtn' type='submit'
```

Button for the login `{{ form }}`:

```
name='loginbtn' type='submit'
```

Now I have trouble trying to login or authenticate the user that I created (which is the super user). My signup/login view goes as follows:

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'signupbtn' in request.POST:
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You may now login.')
            return redirect('index') 
    elif 'loginbtn' in request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password1']
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Is it possible that I need to create 2 forms in my forms.py? When I try to login, it doesn't go past the `form.is_valid()` under `elif 'loginbtn' in request.POST:`. Also both forms have `{% csrf_token %}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got everything to work by just simply REMOVING the `form.is_valid()` and adjusting the view after that.